# jQuery, during the animation disable the hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this animation in jQuery:

```
          $('.menu1').stop().animate({left: "29%", top: '2%', width:'40%', fontSize: '60%'}, 3000);
          $('.menu2').stop().animate({left: "44%", top: '2%', width:'40%', fontSize: '60%'}, 3000);
          $('.menu3').stop().animate({left: "59%", top: '2%',width:'40%', fontSize: '60%'}, 3000);
          $('.menu4').stop().animate({left: "74%", top: '2%', width:'40%', fontSize: '60%'}, 3000);
          $('.menu1').find('.img1').attr("src", "images/botom1.png");
           $('.csoon').fadeToggle( 6000 );
```

And the function of hover:

```
     $('.menu1').hover(function(){
              $('.menu1').stop(true, true).css('font-size','+=5%');
        }, function(){
            $('.menu1').stop(true, true).css('font-size','-=5%');
 });
```

The problem is that during the animation if the mouse is going over the menu, accidentally, than the hover function will still decrease the font-size. How can i disable it?

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jy57u25u/

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: I just edit it and added the JSFiddle :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use a flag

```
$('.menu1').stop().data('my-animation', true).animate({
    left: "29%",
    top: '2%',
    width: '40%',
    fontSize: '60%'
}, 3000, function () {
    $(this).data('my-animation', false)
});
```

then

```
$('.menu1').hover(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).data('my-animation')) {
        $('.menu1').stop(true, true).css('font-size', e.type == 'mouseenter' ? '+=5%' : '-=5%');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**unbind()**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
$('.menu1').unbind('hover');
$('.menu1').stop().animate({left: "29%", top: '2%', width:'40%', fontSize: '60%'}, 3000);
          $('.menu2').stop().animate({left: "44%", top: '2%', width:'40%', fontSize: '60%'}, 3000);
          $('.menu3').stop().animate({left: "59%", top: '2%',width:'40%', fontSize: '60%'}, 3000);
          $('.menu4').stop().animate({left: "74%", top: '2%', width:'40%', fontSize: '60%'}, 3000);
          $('.menu1').find('.img1').attr("src", "images/botom1.png");
           $('.csoon').fadeToggle( 6000 );

$('.menu1').hover(function(){
              $('.menu1').stop(true, true).css('font-size','+=5%');
        }, function(){
            $('.menu1').stop(true, true).css('font-size','-=5%');
 });
```

**Or**, use a flag

```
var animating = false;
$('.menu1').hover(function() {
    if (!animating) {
        $('.menu1').stop(true, true).css('font-size', '+=5%');
    }
}, function() {
    if (!animating) {
        $('.menu1').stop(true, true).css('font-size', '-=5%');
    }
});
animating = true;
$('.menu1').stop().animate({
    left: "29%",
    top: '2%',
    width: '40%',
    fontSize: '60%'
}, 3000);
$('.menu2').stop().animate({
    left: "44%",
    top: '2%',
    width: '40%',
    fontSize: '60%'
}, 3000);
$('.menu3').stop().animate({
    left: "59%",
    top: '2%',
    width: '40%',
    fontSize: '60%'
}, 3000);
$('.menu4').stop().animate({
    left: "74%",
    top: '2%',
    width: '40%',
    fontSize: '60%'
}, 3000);
$('.menu1').find('.img1').attr("src", "images/botom1.png");
$('.csoon').fadeToggle(6000);
animating = false;
```